# 2014 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/2014-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- During the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, August 18th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this new process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Links

**2014 Community Moderator Election Process**

[2014 Community Moderator Election](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/2014-community-moderator-election)

**2 Nomination Candidates in the running** (17th August 2014)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/election

Comment: "Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post one question per answer" - I had to read that 3 times to understand it. Perhaps it could be rephrased, which might lead to more questions (by which I mean answers...)

Answer (score 8):

What do you think is the biggest problem facing this SE? Do you think there needs to be any changes made to the policy or rules - what would you suggest?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 7):

What is your GIS background/experience, and what software packages are your greatest strengths and weaknesses? What approach would you take when needing to moderate a Question/Answer about topics you are less proficient in?

Answer (score 3):

Following up from the questions posted by @Erica:

- If you came across a Question concerning a topic you are less proficient in, would you "flag" it for another moderator (who is more qualified and/or experienced) to examine it?
- Is there a **least** amount of time moderators should spend per day moderating SE, or in particular GIS SE, in order to be as helpful to the community as possible?

Comment: FYI: There is no minimum time required for mods the GIS community (you) help flag questions/spam - mods solve the flagged issues. Theory of Moderation http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/

Comment: I think that Joseph's question still has some value, seeking their personal opinion: "What do you think is the minimum amount of time you should put in to be as helpful to the GIS.SE community as possible?" (Also, I'm curious about whether a candidate has a "check in throughout the day" or "spend lots of time in the morning/evening" goal in mind -- perhaps equal quantity of time spent, but different "coverage" is achieved.)