# 2014 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election, moderators

The 2014 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://gis.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: As of Aug 11, 2014, the •More information about the candidates. link only provides information for the 2013 candidates.  is there a time lag?

Comment: @Dan I believe there is a candidate lag: we will need to wait for people to nominate themselves before information about them can appear!

Comment: There are now 2 Nomination Candidates currently (13th August 2014)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its 2017.