# Advance notice of 2016 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

By about 12 Sep 2016 you will see a notice like [2014 Community Moderator Election](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/2014-community-moderator-election) (from the last election) appear to announce the 2016 Community Moderator Election for GIS SE.

Moderator elections occur on an as needed basis, typically each year or two.  In this case the moderation team seeks to expand its number by two, in order to meet the growing demands of the site, particularly during working hours of the Asia Pacific time zones where I am currently the only one living.

I would encourage all users eligible to nominate, to contemplate whether they might wish to do so now, so that when the Nomination Phase opens on about 12 Sep 2016, you will be in a position to quickly post a small introduction to yourself and why you think you would make a good moderator.

For generic information on the Stack Exchange election process I recommend reviewing [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work)

To see how past elections have been run for GIS SE our Meta Q&As tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election) are probably the place to start.

Feel free to ask questions about the upcoming election any time from now, but there is nothing formal that potential nominees need to do until the formal announcement of the 2016 Community Moderator Election.

Note that Community Moderator Elections are run totally by Stack Exchange staff and not community moderators.  The GIS SE moderators simply say to them that they think it is time for an election for X new moderators (in our case two) because ..., and if they agree (which they did instantly), then they handle the process.  I asked permission from them to post this advance notice because for the last election we only had one nominee for most of the nomination phase.

The 2014 election had 1,704 eligible voters, this one will have at least 2,932.

Comment: Are we increasing the number of moderators? Or is someone stepping down? Or is this the regular election where every Moderator position is up for election?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe it is "to expand its number by two" i.e. Increasing from six to eight. None of the current moderators has indicated an intention to step down. I am not aware of there ever having been an election on a Stack Exchange site where all elected positions were declared vacant. That would be highly irregular indeed.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe maybe you are thinking of the first election after a site's graduation when  the SE appointed pro tem moderators are replaced by the site's first elected moderators.

Comment: Thank you @PolyGeo for taking care of this!

Comment: @PolyGeo: I guess you are right. That is probably what I was thinking of.

Comment: GIS SE receives 1.1m visitors on average every 28 days, that is 100's of moderations flags for attention and this is still a growing site and it is the right time to expand. We [Moderators] have resolved most flags in an average handling time 0 days 1 hours 8 minutes....

Comment: How does one become eligible for voting?

Comment: @HasanMustafa From http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work it looks like anyone with 150 reputation is eligible to vote so you easily qualify to do so.

Comment: According to the 2016 Election page http://gis.stackexchange.com/election/4 a reputation of 300 is required for Nomination "In the nomination phase, any community member in good standing with more than 300 reputation may nominate themselves to be a community moderator"

Comment: 2,934 voters are eligible for the GIS Stack Exchange 2016 Election for Voting (1228 more than the 2014 Election).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the 2016 Community Moderator Election (Nomination Phase) is now underway.  To follow or participate in the election please see http://gis.stackexchange.com/election

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Information for potential nominees... and good luck.

What is expected?

So in summary, if you become a community moderator on the GIS Stack Exchange site, here's what to expect:

> As a moderator, your actions now represent the community, so you will
>   be held to a higher standard of behavior. You are an ambassador of
>   trust, with the same sorts of rights that the official development
>   team and community coordinators have.
>
> Your goal is to guide the community with gentle -- but firm --
>   intervention. Respect your fellow community members at all times;
>   demonstrate fairness and impartiality in your actions.
>
> Whenever possible, try to leave frequent comments on posts where
>   you've taken (or considered taking) a moderator action, explaining the
>   reasoning. This is important so that community members can learn the
>   norms of the community and the moderation policies.
>
> Keep the site reasonably on topic by closing, migrating, or removing
>   blatantly off-topic questions.
>
> Regularly check for flagged posts, and decide if further action is
>   warranted.
>
> In the case of serious disputes, communicate directly with users via
>   email to help mediate and resolve those disputes.

As a moderator you will spend more time on moderation (flagged posts, commenting and taking firm action when required.) than answering questions.

Source:
**"A Theory of Moderation"**

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/